# How to remove the gap between components in flex 4.6 mobile

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, flex4.5

I tried to use two rect components in flex 4.6 mobile. Both were placed in a vgroup. But i could see a gap between the two rect components. Is it possible to customize this gap. I dont think vgroup has a vertical gap property. I want to make the gap 0.

Thanks,
Sukesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Gap property for vgroups and hgroups

```
<s:vgroup gap="0"/>
```

I think the default is 8 if you don't specify it.